# Compare rows and multiple columns within same table SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Compare rows within same table in SQL Server 2012.

Given a table (see script below), what would be the best way to compare rows (individual columns) within the same table?

Example

We are importing data from a client and this can be done many times and we should be able to detect the difference in column's values.

So each time we get the data and we import it we increment our "DataCut" column and then I should be able to compare the difference between datacuts.

If you notice in my sample data  in datacutId 3 the Name-Postcode-Homephone have changed.

How would I report on these differences? Any snippet sql or line of thoughts?

Many thanks

SQL script to create test environment

```
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name='TestDatabase')
        BEGIN
            ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase 
            SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

            DROP DATABASE TestDatabase
        END

        CREATE DATABASE TestDatabase collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
        GO
        ALTER DATABASE TestDatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE  


        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        USE TestDatabase
        IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Customer]', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[Customer];

        GO

        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
            [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [DataCutId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [CustomerId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL,
            [City] [varchar](255) NULL,
            [PostCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
            [HomePhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customer] ON;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer]([Id], [DataCutId],CustomerId, [Name], [Surname], [City], [PostCode], [HomePhone])
        SELECT 1, 1,20, N'Jo', N'Bloggs', N'London', N'aaa 342', N'0207 3456785' UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 2, 20,N'Jo', N'Bloggs', N'London', N'aaa 342', N'0207 3456785' UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 3, 20,N'Mark', N'Bloggs', N'Londong', N'bbb d4543', N'0208 3456785'

        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Customer] OFF;

        COMMIT
```

Comment: Do you have any unique identifier that links different records together?  if you do, then you can link the table to itself

Comment: cannot modify this table but there is no unique identifier to eg joining on the same table multiple times if that is what you mean

Comment: How else will you know then that, in your example, record 1, 2 or 3 is the same person?

Comment: Sorry you are correct. I missed a vital field in my dummy sample "CustomerId" i have updated my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this give you a start to solving your problem?

I am sure there might be an easier way maybe?

```
select a.*, b.DataCutId as UpdDataCutID, b.Name as UpdName, b.Surname as UpdSurname, b.City as UpdCity, b.PostCode as UpdPostCode, b.HomePhone as UpdHomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and a.Name <> b.Name
union 
select a.*, b.DataCutId, b.Name, b.Surname, b.City, b.PostCode, b.HomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and a.Surname <> b.Surname
union 
select a.*, b.DataCutId, b.Name, b.Surname, b.City, b.PostCode, b.HomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and a.City <> b.City
union 
select a.*, b.DataCutId, b.Name, b.Surname, b.City, b.PostCode, b.HomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and a.PostCode <> b.PostCode
union 
select a.*, b.DataCutId, b.Name, b.Surname, b.City, b.PostCode, b.HomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and a.HomePhone <> b.HomePhone
```

**EDIT** I've pulled this all together in a single query below

```
select a.*, b.DataCutId as UpdDataCutID, b.Name as UpdName, b.Surname as UpdSurname, b.City as UpdCity, b.PostCode as UpdPostCode, b.HomePhone as UpdHomePhone
from Customer a inner join Customer b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId 
        and a.Id < b.ID and 
            (a.Name <> b.Name OR 
            a.Surname <> b.Surname OR 
            a.City <> b.City OR 
            a.PostCode <> b.PostCode OR 
            a.HomePhone <> b.HomePhone)
```